# Not finding customer details on OData API exposed in plugin

Tags: sitecore-commerce

We have `Sitecore Commerce 10.1` instance. There is a plugin where we have exposed `OData` API. Inside this API, we would like to get the customer instance by suppling customer id. Using below code

```
var getCustomerCommand = new GetCustomerCommand(this.getCustomerPipeline, base.ServiceProvider);
Customer customer = await getCustomerCommand.Process(CurrentContext, "Entity-Customer-3b53eddd9aeb425bbb1b9d8a83e91e40");
```

The value of customer is always showing null.

We can confirm that the hardcoded customer id exist in the Sitecore commerce.

[image]

Can someone help me in getting the customer object please?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

Try to set `GetCustomerArgument` and then get customers from the `getCustomerPipeline`.

```
var getCustomerArgument = new GetCustomerArgument("YourCustomerId", string.Empty);
Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Customers.Customer customer = await this.getCustomerPipeline.RunAsync(getCustomerArgument, context.CommerceContext.PipelineContext).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: this is also returning null. When I try the same customer id while calling GetCustomer API from the Postman, getting proper response. Thanks.